# When deploying an update on Chrome Store, will downgrading manifest cause any issues with saved data?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension deployed on Google Chrome Store, and I have an update which downgrades from manifest v3 to manifest v2.

Will users who update the extension face loss of data that has been previously saved with chrome.storage?

Comment: It should stay but if your extension wasn't present in the web store before this January they won't allow you to downgrade, AFAICT.

Comment: @wOxxOm will they notify about the downgrade after the review or with an error message right when uploading?